# Is it possible to validate `argparse` default argument values?

Tags: python

Is it possible to tell `argparse` to give the same errors on default argument values as it would on user-specified argument values?

For example, the following will not result in any error:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--choice', choices=['a', 'b', 'c'], default='invalid')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())            # args = {'choice': 'invalid'}
```

whereas omitting the default, and having the user specify `--choice=invalid` on the command-line will result in an error (as expected).

Reason for asking is that I would like to have the user to be able to specify default command-line options in a JSON file which are then set using `ArgumentParser.set_defaults()`, but unfortunately the behaviour demonstrated above prevents these user-specified defaults from being validated.

Update: `argparse` is inconsistent and I now consider the behavior above to be a bug. The following does trigger an error:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--num', type=int, default='foo')

args = parser.parse_args()      # triggers exception in case --num is not 
                                # specified on the command-line
```

I have opened a bug report for this: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100949

Comment: Why not pre-process and check if the default is part of the list? It makes little logical sense to check at runtime if the default is part of choices. I mean, usually you're supposed to set both...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, it would involve repeating myself in the sense that I already declared what I consider valid input as part of setting up the parser. In the example above it would involve checking whether the choice is part of a list. But for Boolean options for example I would need to validate that the user-specified value is actually a Boolean. In short, it would involve duplicating all of the validation logic that is already present in the parser.

Answer (score 2):

I took the time to dig into [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/argparse.py), and what is happening is that a check is only happening for arguments you gave on the command line. The only way to enforce a check, in my opinion, is to subclass ArgumentParser and have it do the check when you add the argument:

```
class ValidatingArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
        self._check_value(self._actions[-1],kwargs['default'])
```

Comment: Interesting approach, the main problem here is that argument groups are hard to support in a nice way without relying on implementation details too much. I've decided to pass `args` explicitly to `parse_args`, where `args` is built up from a combination of arguments from `sys.argv` and arguments defined in JSON, where `sys.argv` takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

No. Explicit arguments need to be validated because they originate from *outside* the source code. Default values originate *in* the source code, so it's the job of the programmer, not the argument parser, to ensure they are valid.

(This is the difference between *validation* and *debugging*.)

(Using `set_defaults` on unvalidated user input still falls under the purview of debugging, as it's not the argument parser itself adding the default values, but the programmer.)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not buying this. `parse_args()` can be called with a list of `args` (maybe originating from within the source code, who knows), which `ArgumentParser` will then happily validate.

Comment: The distinction is when you provide the values: "statically", while you are still *defining* the parser, or "dynamically", when you are *using* the parser. (The ability to pass an explicitly list is, I think, more--not *exclusively*, but more--for testing than for actual use.)

Comment: Before calling `parse_args`, you are responsible for validating the definitional portions of the parser. In `parse_args`, the parser itself tries to validate its *input*.

Comment: That makes sense. But then `argparse` is inconsistent, because the following does trigger an error in case `--num` does not receive any arguments on the command-line: `parser.add_argument('--num', type=int, default='test')`. And I get why it triggers that error, it makes sense. I don't get why it would not trigger that error in the piece of code given in the question.

Comment: Think of it this way: `choices` has nothing to do with what value can be *assigned* to the destination, only which values can be provided on the command line.

Comment: `type` is not doing type checking; it's doing type *conversion*. Any validation it does is more of a side effect of failing at conversion.

Comment: In the end, though, you can argue it's inconsistent, and you may be right, but it's not going to *change*, not after 12+ years in the standard library.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. You're probably right it is not going to change unfortunately. We'll see what comes out of it. In the end I can do what I want by wrapping `ArgumentParser` and modifying `args`, which is kind of ugly IMO. In case the default choice would be validated I could just do `set_defaults()` using the values from JSON and be done with it.

Comment: Years ago, I subclassed it (overriding `parse_args` to do most of the work) to allow options to take values from a `.ini` file or from environment variables. I would probably do something similar with a JSON config: parse the file, but have `parse_args` look in the resulting `dict` for values instead of using them as default values.

Comment: Overriding `parse_args` directly is cleaner than what I'm doing right now probably. I'll have to check because I still want defaults from `add_argument()` to be honored in case the JSON does not specify any values for those arguments, and I dislike having to rely on implementation details of `argparse` in the overridden `parse_args()`  (which as far as I see now that will be hard not to do). Thank you for the suggestion though, I'll try out that approach.